# Show or Export Cut List from Video Sequence Editor as Text?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a way to show or export a list with all data of all strips (channel, frame-start/end/length/..) of a project in video sequence editor?
Like a cut-list, for instance.
I need to compare projects and also since only one project can be opened at a time, comparing this information is cumbersome.

Edit: Even temporarily copying channels is a pain - the more strips are in the channels the harder it is to lock on strip edges.
Or is there a way to achieve this more elegantly?
Thanks a lot, Michael.  (on Blender 3.4.1/macos/Linux)

Comment: Not sure about Linux/Mac, but you can certainly open several instances of Blender at once with different projects under Windows if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding!
Interesting, I don't see how this would be possible?
IAC the current project closes before opening a different one.
On Windows you just open Blender again via the start menu?

Comment: On a second thought, opening a second project only wins 'only half die battle' anyway: Checking if it's cut exactly the same way - to the frame # - isn't possible anyway.

Comment: Yes. You just open another instance from the Start menu (or in my case from the taskbar as Blender is pinned there).

Comment: ok, thank you!  { OT: I just realise, polite form is not a thing here .. it never occured on me reading other SE-forums}

Comment: You could try this EDL exporter. The resulting file can be opened in notepad and carries the data you're asking for: https://github.com/tin2tin/ExportEDL
(I haven't tested it for a while, so it might have been broken, tho)